# Add simple text to panel control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel in C#:

```
    Panel aspPanel = new Panel();
    Button aspbutton = new Button();
    aspbutton.Text = "Download PDF";
    aspbutton.Click += initDownload;
    aspPanel.Controls.Add(aspbutton);`
```

I have added Attributes and buttons and all kinds of cool dynamic stuff. But I want to just add simple text and so far am unsuccessful.

I'm looking for how to add text behind the button. In the end the HTML code would render something like:

```
    <input type="button"/> Hello, this is a button, please click
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just add a label control beside it and set the text property?

Comment: @Xander's answer is the one you want - that let's you add text without any wrapping markup around the text.

Comment: Thanks guys. Now if anyone does a google search on this, they will find "simple" "text" and "panel" "control"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To add [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) text after the button:

```
Panel aspPanel = new Panel();
Button aspbutton = new Button();
aspbutton.Text = "Download PDF";
aspbutton.Click += initDownload;
aspPanel.Controls.Add(aspbutton);

aspPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("some more text!"));
```

Comment: np, i wouldn't waste too much time working with webforms. mvc and webapi is the wave of the future, especially if you're going into hardcore web development ...

Comment: Agreed, but just enough to understand it and move on... which is what I'm doing :)

Comment: Working on native apps is not a waste of time when you consider how lacking today's development tools are; sometimes it is necessary to "go native" to create a new tool that absorbs hard work like a sponge, with minimal latency.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Hello, this is a button, please click";
aspPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: Label is wrapped in <span/> tags, so it isn't technically the solution.

Comment: It will achieve the same thing, when rendered in the browser

Comment: I know in most cases it will basically _look_ the same in the end, there are times where it may not be what is expected- think CSS rules, and it isn't exactly what the questions asked for - that is all I was pointing out - more for the OP than anything.

Comment: I understand. Even Javascript and JQuery specifics too. I actually chose Label because Literal is rarely used. I can't remember the last time I saw it used in any recent examples on the internet. Only in .Net 2.0 days

Comment: To be honest I had thought of this before asking the question. But was really looking for the clean HTML. Thank you though.